# Is there a way to check if someone was sent to a page by a certain other page?

Tags: php

I'm making a site and part of it is additional information after you have signed up. After you have filled out the boxes and all in register.php you're sent to signup.inc.php (Through the post method) and in there, there's some code that checks if you have been sent by the post method in register.php.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["signup-submit"])){
    /* Code for sign up*/
} else {
    header("Location: ../register/register.php");
    exit ();
}
?>
```

I want to do the same thing again but registered.php checking if the person was sent by signup.inc.php to registered.php with some php inside the registered folder. I can't use the method I used before though as there's no post method in signup.inc.php. I use the

```
/*after all script was successfully run and the information was sent to the database*/
("Location: ../register/registered.php");
exit ();
```

method instead. Is there any code I can use to do as I want?

register.php>signup.inc.php>registered.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']!='')
{
 /* Code for sign up*/
} 
else 
{
 header("Location: ../register/register.php");
 exit ();
}
?>
```

You can use the above code, if REFERER is not empty you can write your logic for signup. otherwise it will redirect to register.php

Answer (score 1):

Use can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` header.

The HTTP REFERER in PHP is stored in the $_SERVER super global, and can be referenced from anywhere in your PHP code like this:

```
$previousURL=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

HTTP_REFERER is not always sent by the client user agent, so you can add this to check if it is set or not:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) 
{
    $previousURL=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing I'm doing this wrong?
`
<?php
$previousURL = "http://localhost/MeepMop/includes/signup.inc.php";
if ($previousURL=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) {
    echo "Sent by signup page";
} else {
    echo "Not sent by sign up page";
}
?>
`
I'm getting "Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER" back

Comment: Sometimes HTTP_REFERER is not sent by user agent , therefore you are seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to check from where it is coming. It will be empty if there is no referrer.

Reference:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] will hold the URL of the page reference from which the response came from.

**But in some circumstances the HTTP_REFERER will loss when the request came from an https to http**

I have experienced this once in an application when the final request of payment gateway came from their https server to our http server.